# How can I make my mousebutton4 act exactly as Enter?

Tags: modeling

I wish to be able to get into quick favourites (by pressing q), then I want to scroll to my favourite of choice and confirm my selection. I now have to press the return key, I wish to make my mousebutton4 on my mouse to act exactly as the return key to confirm my selection in the menu. Does someone know how to do this?[image]

Comment: Probably your best bet is to map the button in your operating system. On Windows you'd use Autohotkey for that.

Comment: The problem then is that I cant use my mouse buttons for other things in windows, I use mousebutton5 and 4 when using my browser for example. Isnt this possible to achieve within blender only?

Comment: If you're on Windows, you can use the power toys keyboard manager program:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager
It lets you limit a remapping of a key to only a specific app. In your case, you could remap your mouse button to enter and limit it to only work in Blender.

Comment: In Autohotkey you can also easily limit a mapping to a single application - wrap your mappings between `#if WinActive("ahk_exe blender.exe")` and `#if`.